# Python interface not working (Clojure + Vim)

Tags: python, vim, clojure

Sorry for that, I think I'm really mistaking in something simple because I could not even find someone with a similar problem after some googling.

I firstly got the error when I tried to use fireplace's `:Connect.`

Apparently it is installed (but not corretly, because `:help fireplace` doesn't work) but it returns `Python interface not working`.

Again, sorry for this newbie question.

Comment: First, what is the question? Second, why don't you use fireplace's issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

> [The only external dependency is that you have either a Vim with Python support compiled in, or `python` in your path.](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace#features)

There you have it. Make sure you have Python in your path (typing `python` on the command-line brings up a Python interpreter), or install a Vim with Python support (in Vim, `:echo has('python')` returns 1). You can find many many questions and answers with the details for both of these on Stack Overflow.